# Angular wait for promise in sqlite insert

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, angular-promise

I need to insert x rows into the DB. Here is my code:

```
dataFactory.insertData = function (responseData)
        {
            var q = $q.defer();
            var rows = 0;
            $.each(responseData, function (index, value)
            {
                var query = "insert or ignore into ...";
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res)
                {
                    rows += 1;
                }, function (err)
                {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            });
            q.resolve(rows);
            return q.promise;
        };
```

How can I wait for all inserts to finish before calling resolve? I believe that the q.promise will get resolved before all rows are inserted.

Comment: I think inside each apply check like if(rows === responseData.length) means all data inserted in db .

Comment: Thats ok, but not the problem. I want to resolve the promise once all inserts are completed. I think the resolve will get called before all rows are inserted.

Comment: resolve the promise inside the above check .

Comment: But I need to wait for all inserts to complete. Won't the check run before all inserts are completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try the below code**

```
  dataFactory.insertData = function (responseData)
            {
                var q = $q.defer();
                var rows = 0;
                var howManyRecordProcessed =0;
                $.each(responseData, function (index, value)
                {
                    //... prepare data...
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res)
                    {
                       //response after db save 
                        howManyRecordProcessed++;  //increment variable
                        if(howManyRecordProcessed === responseData.length)
{
  //resolve here
  q.resolve(rows);
}
                        rows += 1;
                    }, function (err)
                    {
                      //if some error occured.
                        howManyRecordProcessed++;
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                });
                q.resolve(rows);
                return q.promise;
            };
```

**OR**  May be move the db save logic to another which will return promise when all saved .